# PHP dropdown menu values sorting and separation with respect to similar ID's

Tags: php, html, dropdown

Here is the mysql table named "**subject**"

```
| ID | Name |
|----|------|
| 32 | Name1 |
| 32 | Name2 |
| 32 | Name3 |
| 28 | Name4 |
| 28 | Name5 |
| 33 | Name6 |
| 33 | Name7 |
| 41 | Name8 |
| 55 | Name9 |
```

I would like to give a separation after all the similar ID's

```
<select>
<?php

   $count_line = 0;
   $sql="SELECT * FROM subject";
   $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

?>     
 <option><?php echo $row['Name'];?></option>
<?php 
     if ($count_line == 2) {
       echo "<optgroup label='--------------------'></optgroup> ";
       $count_line=0;
     }
     $count_line++;
}   
?>
</select>
```

In my code separate line will show after every two records.I would like to display the separate line after every similar ID's in the dropdown menu.

I would like to get the output like as shown in the picture. 
[image]

Please do help someone to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

```
<select>
<?php
$count_line = 0;
$row_id = '';
 $sql="SELECT * FROM subject";
$result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>     
 <?php 
if($count_line != 0 && $row_id != $row['ID']) 
{
echo "<optgroup label='--------------------'></optgroup> ";
}
 <option><?php echo $row['Name'];?></option>
$count_line++;
$row_id = $row['ID'];
}   
?>
</select>
```

Comment: And don't forget to specify an order- either within the query itself, or when parsing the array

Comment: it is sorting, but only last record of each ID will display is into the previous ID's